# Clarification of methods being called using a stoplight example

Tags: java

The code below appears in my book in the chapter about Methods. I'm a little confused about a couple of things.

1. Is my understanding correct when I believe that the `run()` method is calling the `createFilledCircle` method?
2. Is the `run()` method the receiver and the `createFilledCircle` the sender?
3. for the three `add(createFilledCircles...red,yellow and green);` how does the programmer know what information is permitted in the argument? Is the format of `(x location, y location, width of figure, height of figure)` being used in the `add(createFilledCircle)`?

```
import acm.program.*;
import acm.graphics.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class StopLight extends ConsoleProgram {
  public void run() {
    double cy = getWidth() / 2 ;
    double cx=  getHeight() / 2; 

    double fx = cx - (FRAME_WIDTH / 2);
    double fy = cy - (FRAME_HEIGHT /2 );

    double dy = (FRAME_HEIGHT / 4 ) + (LAMP_RADIUS / 2);

    GRect frame = new GRect (fx, fy, FRAME_WIDTH, FRAME_HEIGHT);
    frame.setFilled(trye);
    frame.setColor(Color.GRAY);
    add(frame);

    add(createFilledCircle(cx, cy-dy, LAMP_RADIUS, Color.RED));
    add(createFilledCircle(cx, cy, LAMP_RADIUS, Color.YELLOW));
    add(createFilledCircle(cx, cy + dy, LAMP_RADIUS, Color.GREEN));
  }

  private GOval createFilledCircle (double x, double y, double r, Color color) {
    GOval circle = new GOval (x -r, y -r, 2 * r, 2 * y );
    circle.setFilled(true);
    circle.setColor(color);
    return circle; 
  }

  private static final double FRAME_WIDTH = 50; 
  private static final double FRAME_HEIGHT = 100;
  private static final LAMP_RADIUS = 10; 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1) Is my understanding correct when I believe that the run() method is calling the createFilledCircle method?

Yes.

> 2) Is the run() method the receiver and the createFilledCircle the sender?

I don't know what you mean by "receiver" and "sender". Those are not terms that people normally use when talking about methods being called.

(It looks like teminology from the Smalltalk programming language, which was an early object oriented language. In the light of that, it's exactly the other way around: you'd say `run` is the sender and `createFilledCircle` is the receiver.)

> 3) for the three add(createFilledCircles...red,yellow and green); how does the programmer know what information is permitted in the argument? Is the format of (x location, y location, width of figure, height of figure) being used in the add(createFilledCircle)?

The declaration of the `createFilledCircle` method specifies what parameters that method needs: three `double` values and a `Color` value.

In a line such as this one:

```
add(createFilledCircle(cx, cy-dy, LAMP_RADIUS, Color.RED));
```

what happens is that `createFilledCircle` is called first, with the arguments `cx, cy-dy, LAMP_RADIUS, Color.RED`, and then the return value of the method `createFilledCircle`, which is a `GOval` value, is passed to the `add` method. It's the same as this:

```
GOval result = createFilledCircle(cx, cy-dy, LAMP_RADIUS, Color.RED);
add(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

> 1) Is my understanding correct when I believe that the run() method is calling the createFilledCircle method?

Yes, it is correct. It is being called here inside so output of `createFilledCircle` is parameter to `add` method.

```
add(createFilledCircle(cx, cy-dy, LAMP_RADIUS, Color.RED));
```

> 2) Is the run() method the receiver and the createFilledCircle the sender?

I don't think it is proper terminology for this code. There is no sending and receiving.
Object gets created inside `createFilledCircle`. `run` adds that object to itself.

Answer (score 0):

`1) Is my understanding correct when I believe that the run() method is calling the createFilledCircle method?`

Yes.

`2) Is the run() method the receiver and the createFilledCircle the sender?`

In object oriented programming, `sender` and `receiver` are usually the objects or classes which participate in a communication. In your case, the `StopLight` instance itself would be both sender and receiver when calling the `createFilledCircle` method from within `run`. As another example, in `frame.setFilled(trye);`, the `StopLight` instance (`this`) is the sender, and `frame` is the receiver of the `setFilled` message (in Java, a message in OOP sense is basically a method call).

`3) for the three add(createFilledCircles...red,yellow and green); how does the programmer know what information is permitted in the argument? Is the format of (x location, y location, width of figure, height of figure) being used in the add(createFilledCircle)?`

The programmer usually knows this through the documentation or by looking at the source code :-)

There must be at least one `add` method somewhere in your class hierarchy, and you need to look at the parameter list of those methods to know which arguments are permitted. Ideally there is a JavaDoc documentation available which not only lists the parameter types itself, but also gives some insight in how to use them and what the respective method actually does.
In your case, since `createFilledCircle` returns a `GOval` reference, there needs to be an `add` method which takes a type compatible with `GOval` as a parameter. Likewise, the `createFilledCircle` method (which is declared in your class itself) takes three `double` values and one `Color` object reference, and this is actually how you also call it.

Answer (score 0):

1) Yes - it calls it at

```
add(createFilledCircle(cx, cy-dy, LAMP_RADIUS, Color.RED));
  add(createFilledCircle(cx, cy, LAMP_RADIUS, Color.YELLOW));
  add(createFilledCircle(cx, cy + dy, LAMP_RADIUS, Color.GREEN));
```

2)  It is the sender, but the add() method is the receiver.

3)   createFilledCircle has specified its method parameters with...

```
createFilledCircle (double x, double y, double r, Color color)
```

Comment: No worries - up vote some the answers you like on here - it makes us feel all warm an fuzzy :3